# How to define non-autonomous dynamical system - "invariance solution" property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Taking a look in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system), we found

$${\displaystyle \Phi (t_{2},\Phi (t_{1},x))=\Phi (t_{2}+t_{1},x),}$$

as part of the definition of dynamical systems.

I am new in this area, so I ask:

1. This is the same that the so called "[invariance solution](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Waves_and_Acoustics/The_Physics_of_Waves_(Goergi)/01%3A_Harmonic_Oscillation/1.03%3A_Time_Translation_Invariance)" property?
2. This "invariance solution" property is about autonomous system, isn't? If yes, how to propose non-autonomous dynamical systems?

These two questions are about the same ideia: in a dynamical system, I can put any point in a trajectory and the solution for that initial condition will have the same orbit. Am I right?

For instance, what about $dx/dt=t$? The orbit will change if I start in other point of the trajectory... Is this a dynamical system?

Thank you so much.

Comment: When citing a reference, it is generally useful to provide a link to that reference. In any way, 

1. This is the semigroup property. 
2. It depends what you mean by non-autonomous. If the system has no inputs but its dynamical model depends on time explicitly, then the above formula is still valid. If the system has inputs then the state will depend on the state-transition matrix and an an integral term that depends on the input. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix

Comment: The link was added, thank you and sorry by that. You can post the comment as answer, I think. About the "semigroup property", this is also called invariance of solution or they are different things? About state-transtition matrix, so the formula is not exactly this semigroup property...? Thank you!

Comment: For instance, what about $dx/dt=t$? The orbit will change if I start in other point of the trajectory...

Comment: I am not sure what you refer to by " invariance of solution". I have never seen that anywhere. Where did you see that term? I am not sure what you want to say by " the formula is not exactly this semigroup property" and also your last question. Of course, if the initial condition or the initial time changes, then the trajectory will be different.

Comment: @KBS, I hope that I've explained better in the question now. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: The link you posted is about time-invariance of the dynamical system, meaning that the behavior of the system at some time $t$ is the same as at some other time $t'$. The dynamical system $\dot{x}(t)=ax(t)$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is time invariant. The dynamical system $\dot{x}(t)=tx(t)$ is not time-invariant, but time-varying. Finally, the example you gave is indeed a dynamical system whose state is given by $x(t)=t^2/2$. In this case, the system has an input and this is not captured by the $\Phi$ formula you gave which is for system with no input.

Comment: OK... So, the formal definition given here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system#Formal_definition) is, in fact, a particular definition said "dynamical system with no input"...? Thank you and sorry by my slowness....

Comment: Yes. Also, I made a mistake with the solution of your system as I forgot the initial condition. This should be $x(t)=x(0)+t^2/2$. In that case, we have that $\Phi(t,s,x)=\Psi(t,s)x=x$ for all $t,s\ge0$, $t\ge s$, where $\Psi(t,s)$ is a matrix (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) and $$x(t)=\Psi(t,s)x(s)+\int_s^t\Psi(t,\theta)\theta^2d\theta.$$

Comment: @KBS That's perfect. If you do not matter, I would like to ask you a last question: could you give me an example of a simple system that is NOT a dynamical system? I also ask you to post your comments as an answer and I'll be happy to bount you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134632/discussion-between-kbs-and-quiet-waters).

Comment: What else do you need to know?

Comment: @KBS, nothing, I just started the bounty, so in 24h I can bounty you :)

Comment: OK :) I hope this is clearer for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted is about time-invariance of the dynamical system, meaning that the behavior of the system at some time $t$ is the same as at some other time $t′$.

For instance, the dynamical system $\dot{x}(t)=ax(t)$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is time invariant. If you start the system at time $t_0$ from the state $x(t_0)=x_0$ and if you start the system at time $t_1\ne t_0$ from the state $x(t_1)=x_0$, then the two trajectories will be translated versions of each other.

The dynamical system $\dot{x}(t)=tx(t)$ is not time-invariant, but time-varying. In this case, the initial time will matter.

The composition formula
$${\displaystyle \Phi (t_{2},\Phi (t_{1},x))=\Phi (t_{2}+t_{1},x),}$$
works for both time-varying and time-invariant systems (with no input).

Finally, the example you gave is indeed a dynamical system whose state is given by $x(t)=x(t_0)+(t-t_0)^2/2$. In this case, the system has an input and this is not captured by the $\Phi$ formula you gave which is for systems with no input. In fact, the solution to that system is given by

$$x(t)=\Psi(t,s)x(s)+\int_s^t\Psi(t,\theta)\theta d\theta,$$

where $\Phi(t,s,x)=\Psi(t,s)x=x$, $t\ge s$, and where $\Psi(t,s)$ is the so-called state transition matrix (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix). Finally, since the system is time-varying, the trajectory will not only depend on the initial condition but also on the initial time.

If you want to know more about dynamical systems, you may look at "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" by Steven Strogatz. It is usually a good starting point.